# python, tensorflow, how to get a tensor shape with half the features

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need the shape of a tensor, except instead of feature_size as the -1 dimension I need feature_size//2

The code I'm currently using is

```
_, half_output = tf.split(output,2,axis=-1)

half_shape = tf.shape(half_output)
```

This works but it's incredibly inelegant. I don't need an extra copy of half the tensor, I just need that shape. I've tried to do this other ways but nothing besides this bosh solution has worked yet.

Anyone know a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the shape with the last value halved:

```
half_shape = tf.shape(output[..., 1::2])
```

What it does is simply iterate `output` in its last dimension with step 2, starting from the second element (index 1).

The `...` doesn't touch other dimensions. As a result, you will have `output[..., 1::2]` with the same dimensions as `output`, except for the last one, which will be sampled like the following example, resulting in half the original value.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(5,5)
>>> a
array([[ 0.21553665,  0.62008421,  0.67069869,  0.74136913,  0.97809012],
       [ 0.70765302,  0.14858418,  0.47908281,  0.75706245,  0.70175868],
       [ 0.13786186,  0.23760233,  0.31895335,  0.69977537,  0.40196103],
       [ 0.7601455 ,  0.09566717,  0.02146819,  0.80189659,  0.41992885],
       [ 0.88053697,  0.33472285,  0.84303012,  0.10148065,  0.46584882]])
>>> a[..., 1::2]
array([[ 0.62008421,  0.74136913],
       [ 0.14858418,  0.75706245],
       [ 0.23760233,  0.69977537],
       [ 0.09566717,  0.80189659],
       [ 0.33472285,  0.10148065]])
```

This `half_shape` prints the following `Tensor`:

> Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)

Alternatively you could get the shape of `output` and create the shape you want manually:

```
s = output.get_shape().as_list()
half_shape = tf.TensorShape(s[:-1] + [s[-1] // 2])
```

This `half_shape` prints a `TensorShape` showing the shape halved in the last dimension.

Comment: I tried creating it manually. It didn't want to accept 'none' as the 0th input. I'd try your first suggestion now, but the learning algorithm is already one hour into an eight hour training routine. I'll be sure to try it first thing in the morning tho. Thank-you.

Comment: That's odd... how did you try it? I have no problem with `tf.TensorShape([None])`. Keep us updated, then. Good luck!

Comment: `half_shape = tf.shape(output[..., ::2])` works perfectly, but how does it work?

Comment: I tried something like `s = output.getshape().as_list()`     `s[-1]=out_features//2`    `halfshape = tf.TensorShape(s)`   it gave me an error about needing to cast `s` before using it. I tried casting `s` as an array but it wouldn't accept `none` in the 0th position.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `print(s)` before the error? I'll edit my answer to explain `tf.shape(output[..., ::2])` more in detail.